# How do I increase a variables value only after all the awaits is executed in a map so that I can execute the promises paralley?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, web3js

Hey this is a very basic question but I am getting problem in it. I have following code:

```
var nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAccount);
    hashes.map(async hash => {
    console.log(nonce)
    const account = await web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_1)
    const transaction = await contract.methods.submitHash(hash);
    const options  = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
        to      : transaction._parent._address,
        data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address}),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('20', 'gwei')),
    };
    const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
    console.log(receipt)
    nonce ++}
```

I want to increase nonce only once all the awaits are executed each time ie, I want to get 1,2,3,4.. as nonce value. But the problem is due to asynchronus nature nonce gets the same value in each loop ie 1,1,1,1.. How to increase it by one in each loop execution?

Comment: why a map without return? use foreach

Comment: `hashes.map(async (hash, index) => {...  nonce = index; ...}`

Comment: @ErnestoAlfonso - Not a bad idea if the work can be done in parallel! But it would need to be `nonce + index` each time, since we don't know the initial value of `nonce`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `map` where you want a `for` loop. There are two problems with that:

1. It doesn't make sense to use `map` when you're not using the array it returns (*someone*, somewhere, is teaching this anti-pattern and doing a disservice to their students); and
2. `map` doesn't do anything with the promise your `async` function returns, so all of your `async` functions run in parallel

With a `for` loop, you don't have those problems:

```
let nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAccount);
for (const hash of hashes) {
    console.log(nonce);
    const account = await web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_1);
    const transaction = await contract.methods.submitHash(hash);
    const options = {
        nonce   : web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
        to      : transaction._parent._address,
        data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address}),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('20', 'gwei')),
    };
    const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
    console.log(receipt);
    ++nonce;
}
```

Since your `for` is inside a context where `await` works (an `async` function or, soon, the top level of a module), it waits at the `await` expressions before continuing its logic.

---

**If** the work can be done in parallel, then you could use `map` and `await Promise.all` on the array it returns. Within the `map` callback, use `nonce + index` instead of incrementing since `index` will be `0` for the first hash, `1` for the next, etc.:

```
// In parallel
let nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAccount);
const results = await Promise.all(hashes.map(async (hash, index) => {
    const thisNonce = nonce + index;
    console.log(thisNonce);
    const account = await web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_1);
    const transaction = await contract.methods.submitHash(hash);
    const options = {
        nonce   : web3.utils.toHex(thisNonce),
        to      : transaction._parent._address,
        data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address}),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('20', 'gwei')),
    };
    const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
    console.log(receipt);
}));
// If you're going to keep using `nonce`, do `nonce += results.length` here.
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. The problem doesnt persist anymore just tried it..

Comment: Hey Thanks. In await Promise.all what will happen if one process throws an error? Does all get cancelled?

Comment: @Subik - Your best bet with questions like that is to find some authoritative information, for instance [the MDN page on `Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). `Promise.all` rejects its promise the first time it sees a rejection from any of the promises you give it. Nothing gets *cancelled*, there's no coordination between the promises other than what you provide.